# Glyphicon to right of label erroneously wrapping to next line?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.4, and I want to include popovers triggered via glyphicons to the right of form labels. However, when a label exceeds one line of text, the glyphicon is pushed to the next line. See [BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/4PCL9EhlB6).

How can I achieve the desired effect, that is - the glyphicon should immediately follow the end of the label text regardless of how many lines of text the label generates?

One thing to note is that I'm using .NET MVC Core 1.0 TagHelpers to create the `label` and custom `<asp-popover>` and `<asp-popover-body>` tags. This might limit the expressiveness of allowable HTML, as I can't place anything inside the `label` tags without it completely replacing my label text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `display:inline;` to `<label>` and `<asp-popover>` tags.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="TimeBetweenProducts" style="display:inline;">This label is much longer and will wrap to a new line. The resulting 100% width inline-block label causes the glyphicon to appear on its own line</label>
    <asp-popover style="display:inline;"><i title="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-original-title="" data-toggle="popover" data-popover-content="#TimeBetweenProducts" data-container="body" data-placement="top">
      </i>
    </asp-popover>
    <input class="form-control" type="text">
  </div>
```